# ManyToOne mapping and findingBySchoolId

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create teacher and school objects where 1 school can have multiple teachers, but each teacher works at one school. I am tying to make a query where I get only teachers that work at certain school by getting its id as a parameter.

School object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="school")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class School {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "school_sequence",
            sequenceName = "school_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "school_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany//(mappedBy = "school")
    private List<Teacher> teacher;
}
```

Teacher object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="teacher")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "teacher_sequence",
            sequenceName = "teacher_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "teacher_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
/*    @Column(name="schoolId")
    private Long schoolId;*/

    //(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) Don't use this! it will prevent you to have different teacher queries with
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "schoolId", referencedColumnName = "id")    //the same school ids.
    private School school;

}
```

Teacher controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/teacher")
public class TeacherController {

    private final TeacherService teacherService;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherController(TeacherService teacherService) {
        this.teacherService = teacherService;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Teacher> getTeacher(){
        return teacherService.getTeacher();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "schoolID")
    public List<Teacher> getTeacherBySchool(@PathVariable("schoolId") Long schoolId, School school){
        return teacherService.getTeacherBySchool(schoolId, school);
    }
```

Teacher Service

```
@Service
public class TeacherService {
    private final TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherService(TeacherRepository teacherRepository) {
        this.teacherRepository = teacherRepository;
    }


    public List<Teacher> getTeacher(){
        return teacherRepository.findAll();
    }

    //public List<Teacher> getTeacherBySchool
```

How would I implement this on teacher controller and teacher service?

Update on my progress!!!

Teacher Controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/teachers/{schoolID}")
public List<Teacher> getTeacherBySchool(@PathVariable("schoolID") Long schoolId){
    School school = new School();
    school.setId(schoolId);
    return teacherService.getTeacherBySchool(school);
}
```

Teacher Service

```
   public List<Teacher> getTeacherBySchool(Long schoolId){
            return teacherRepository.findBySchool(school);
}
```

Teacher Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TeacherRepository extends JpaRepository<Teacher, Long> {

    @Query
    List<Teacher> findBySchool(List<School> school);
```

These changes do what I want them to do, but as I said. It is not a good coding practice. What I want is that less code on TeacherController, and make my TeacherService communicate with SchoolService to get the right schools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add the following to your repository:

```
public List<Teacher> findBySchoolId(Long schoolId);
```

Or just write the query yourself:

```
entityManager.createQuery("FROM Teacher t WHERE t.school.id = :schoolId")
    .setParameter("schoolId", schoolId)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Why not just use 
@Query("From Teacher t WHERE t.school.id = :schoolId")
public List<Teacher> findBySchoolId(Long schoolId);


In Repository interface?

Comment: Heck, there are so many different possibilities. I personally hate the Spring Data Repositories because you can't use hot-code replacement during debugging and always have to restart the app.

Comment: It is possible to do that in Spring Boot application. More info on that: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with 
Also it requires slightly more RAM than usual (especially if your machine is equipped with 8GB RAM)